# Prevent Window resizing on Java (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

im using Netbeans 7 for make a desktop application.

But i can't find how to disable Window Resizing or Maximizing in the Gui Builder!, someone can help me?

Comment: The Java API has what you need. Look up the methods available to JFrame and its ancestors.

Comment: *"i can't find how to disable Window Resizing"*  A better option is to make a resizable GUI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access properties of the JFrame (that corresponds to FrameView) directly (in GUI builder's UI), but you can can access it using getFrame() on the FrameView.

For example, to make frame not resizable:

```
getFrame().setResizable(false)
```

in the ApplicationView constructor

Comment: Actually, since this is a property, it can be changed in the Properties window (usually on the right)

Comment: Hmm i didn't find any property to change the resizable value... i'm trying to use @Mademoiselle Geek method :).. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the frame-->properties --> resizable (uncheck)